# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing openweathermap api response data node.js

Tags: javascript, json, openweathermap

i am using openweathermap API. When i try to parse response data to json it gives me an error.
i dont know what to do about this can anyone help??

CODE:

```
const express =  require("express");

const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=faa02526fbe231fa9d2dc1aa991a26f2&q=London";

https.get(url, function (response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    response.on("data", function (data) {
        JSON.parse(data);

    });
});    

res.send("upp and running");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("up and running"); 
});
```

console output:

up and running
200
undefined:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\webdevel\WeatherProject\app.js:14:18)

at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:375:28)

at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:500:10)

at flow (internal/streams/readable.js:982:34)

at resume_ (internal/streams/readable.js:963:3)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Are you sure you can just freely share that `appid` in the URL? Looks a bit like an API key.

Comment: Also could you add a `console.log(data)` (or a breakpoint) before the `JSON.parse(data)` and see what `data` actually is? If I visit the URL, it does display valid JSON, but maybe you're getting an unexpected/different response body. **EDIT**: Ah I think I see what's wrong, let me write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you think that `.on("data", handler)` will only be called once with the full reply. That's not how the API works, check the documentation.

Basically, the response body is streamed in. The `data` event can be emitted many times, each with a chunk of the body response. Therefore, buffer all the data and wait for the response to finish:

```js
https.get(url, function (response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    let resultData = '';
    response.on('data', data => resultData += data);
    response.on('end', () => {
        // Now we got the whole response body
        JSON.parse(resultData);
    });
});
```

Comment: i'm still getting same error and also i did console.log the data and it's in hexadecimal FYI

Comment: @ParzivalOasis Not sure why it's in hexadecimal, but you can easily find a way to convert it to UTF-8 
using e.g. Buffer.